# Mirror Binding value with Published in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

How can I connect Binding value of View to Published value of ObservableObject?

The goal: all changes of objValue will be reflected on viewValue and vice versa.

Note: Do not propose direct onChange(obj.objValue) { viewValue = $0 } modifier. It will trigger extra drawing cycle of View (first for objValue and second for viewValue).

```
class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objValue: Int = 0
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var viewValue: Int
    @StateObject var obj = MyObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Placeholder")
            .onChange(viewValue) {
                //Do something
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass `MyObject` instead if `Int`?

Comment: Because it's being used as StateObject here, there is no need to increase complexity and impulse client to create and inject MyObject that is 100% for internal purpose of View.

Comment: Example: Imagine you have to inject different objects into any standard component like Text or VStack.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `obj.objValue` in the onChange?

Comment: adding the modifier `.onChange` to `Text("Placeholder")` is completely useless, the Text will NEVER change.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine viewValue will change and onChange will be triggered on any view. No matter it's a Text or no. Text can't change by the way, it's just a function which will be recalculated each redraw cycle. Data can change.

Comment: @AdamLeet If there would be no reason to not use onChange, this question would not exist.

Comment: A change in both `obj.objValue` and `viewValue`, could (usually does) refresh the view twice, 
and sometimes more depending on the structure. This is by design and what is expected. 
From the docs: 
`SwiftUI ....(refresh) can happen repeatedly during the life of the view, typically in response to user input or system events.` In other words do not rely on specific number of updates  
in your code. In SwiftUI, if the view refreshes the view twice, well so be it. You can try using UIKit, the event-driven UI, instead of the declarative SwiftUI.

Comment: I just don’t think continuing explaining would be productive. MyObj is actually a bridge to UIKit already (delegate to underlying uiscrollview). Please, we have a question, none other suggestion with completely different workaround will work. Please only if you have an answer to the current question. I will not use another workaround here, the question exists and clear. Thank you.

Comment: No need to give -1 if you just don’t know the answer. Thank you!

Comment: And what means “usually does”? There is a clear rules when it WILL redraw the view or NO. It’s not a random thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution (not directly with Combine yet) that is utilising the View adapter that let us to avoid extra redraw of the MyView body.
By passing the Binding value to ValueReader View, only its body will be triggered to redraw, then it is just passing the new result outside and we can work with it. Here we assign the updated value of viewValue to objValue.

This technique is avoiding extra redraw cycles, MyView body will be redrawn only ONCE, no matter if objValue or viewValue was changed first.
Because viewValue is not being used directly in the body, only ValueReader will be redrawn directly on viewValue change skipping MyView's body redraw.

```
class MyObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objValue: Int = 0
}

struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var viewValue: Int
    @StateObject var obj = MyObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ValueReader(value: $viewValue) { newValue in
                obj.objValue = newValue //Mirroring viewValue to obj.objValue
            }
            
            Text("Placeholder")
                .onChange(of: obj.objValue, perform: handleValue)
        }
    }
    
    private func handleValue(_ value: Int) {
        viewValue = value //Mirroring obj.objValue to viewValue

        //Do any job here. For example just send analytics
    }
    
    private struct ValueReader: View {
        @Binding var value: Int
        let onChange: (_ newValue: Int) -> ()
        
        var body: some View {
            Color.clear
                .onChange(of: value) { newValue in
                    onChange(newValue)
                }
        }
    }
}
```